# Gear S3 accelerometer very slow

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-gear

I'm using Gear S3 and after update its accelerometer got very slow. Before updated I registered 20-25 samples in 30s. Now, I register 10-12 samples. Someone knows why trouble?

```
var t0 = 0;
var cont = 0;

function onDeviceMotion(event){
    var x = event.acceleration.x.toFixed(2);
    var y = event.acceleration.y.toFixed(2);
    var z = event.acceleration.z.toFixed(2);
    var t = ((new Date().getSeconds() + 60) - t0)%60;

    var components = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    z: z,
    t : t
    }

    counter.innerHTML = cont++;
    start.innerHTML = components.t;

    console.log(components.x + " " + components.y + " " + components.z + " " + components.t+ " " + new Date().getSeconds() );

}


window.addEventListener('devicemotion', onDeviceMotion);
```

Comment: Please give fw versions, I can try to compare on TM1 mobile too

Comment: You may try after resetting your gear.....or you can use Tizen provided API for Accelerometer
https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors/device-sensors#capability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the device you may want to use `ACCELERATION` or `LINEAR_ ACCELERATION`. You can check available sensors by calling `tizen.sensorservice.getAvailableSensors();` In my case it was `LINEAR_ACCELERATION` (Samsung Gear Sport). Also you can modify how often you want the callbacks from the sensor (1000 is once per second).

```js
function startAccelerometerSensor() {
 var accelerationSensor = tizen.sensorservice
   .getDefaultSensor("LINEAR_ACCELERATION");
 accelerationSensor.setChangeListener(onChangedCBAccelerometer, 1000);
 accelerationSensor.start(onSuccessCBAccelerometer);
}

function onSuccessCBAccelerometer() {
 console.log('Accelerometer service has started successfully.');
}

function onChangedCBAccelerometer(sensorData) {
 console.log("######## Get ACCELEROMETER sensor data ########");
 console.log("X : " + sensorData.x);
 console.log("Y : " + sensorData.y);
 console.log("Z : " + sensorData.z);
}
```

here is the [documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/sensor.html&langredirect=1#AccelerationSensor::getAccelerationSensorData)